Pandoc latex to word does not work well with \citep and \citet
I'm using the following config, along with \citep and \citet to make my references. Here is the config in my sty file:
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,natbib=true,url=false,uniquelist=false,mincitenames=1,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

When building the pdf I experence no problems, however, when using pandoc to convert to a word document, it does not seem compatible. I'll provide example:
.tex:
For example, \citet{kimReviewFaultDetection2018, mirnaghiFaultDetectionDiagnosis2020, zhaoArtificialIntelligencebasedFault2019,shiDevelopmentImplementationAutomated2019,melgaardFaultDetectionDiagnosis2022} covered extensive overviews of the literature on fault diagnostics in buildings systems.

.pdf: (using pdflatex - this is how I want it)
For example, Kim and Katipamula (2018), Melgaard et al. (2022), Mirnaghi and Haghighat (2020), Shi and O’Brien (2019), and Zhao et al. (2019) covered extensive overviews of the literature on fault diagnostics in buildings systems.

.docx: (using pandoc - this is not correct)
For example, Kim & Katipamula (2018; Melgaard et al., 2022; Mirnaghi & Haghighat, 2020; Shi & O’Brien, 2019; Zhao et al., 2019) covered extensive overviews of the literature on fault diagnostics in buildings systems.

I'm using the following command to generate the docx
pandoc paper.tex --bibliography=MyLibrary.bib --csl=apa.csl --citeproc -o paper.docx

using this csl https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/apa.csl
Any suggestions for how I can solve this would be so appreciated!!!

Welcome to TeX.SE. Do citation commands other than \citet (and \citep) work as they should under pandoc?

Most of the convertor having problem with name&year style tags, you better try with make4ht with open office conversion option

I guess it would work if you write it out, i.e., \citet{kimReviewFaultDetection2018}, \citet{mirnaghiFaultDetectionDiagnosis2020}, \citet{zhaoArtificialIntelligencebasedFault2019}, \citet{shiDevelopmentImplementationAutomated2019} and \citet{melgaardFaultDetectionDiagnosis2022}.

@Mico, yes as far as I know

@Marijn, yes, that does work! There are two problems, though. First, my document is quite long, and this fix would have been something I would have had to plan from the beginning (or create a script). But the bigger problem is that the references would not be ordered automatically, which, depending on the format, can be important (e.x. IEEE format because it's numbered).
